# Application not working when installing LocalNotification plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

my app was running fine until i installed **Local Notifications** native plugin:

I executed this command :  `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification`

then this one `npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications`

Then i added `import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';` on app.module.ts

Then i added `LocalNotifications` on the provider part of NgModule

Then i added `import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';` on my home.ts

Then i added `public localNotifications: LocalNotifications,` to the constructor parameter

Then i tried to run the app and it dont wanna build, here's the log:

```
    $ ionic cordova run android --target=95142bf1
    Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
    [01:14:05]  build dev started ...
    [01:14:05]  clean started ...
    [01:14:05]  clean finished in 15 ms
    [01:14:05]  copy started ...
    [01:14:05]  deeplinks started ...
    [01:14:05]  deeplinks finished in 171 ms
    [01:14:05]  transpile started ...
    [01:14:10]  transpile finished in 5.13 s
    [01:14:10]  preprocess started ...
    [01:14:10]  preprocess finished in 15 ms
    [01:14:10]  webpack started ...
    [01:14:11]  copy finished in 5.79 s
    [01:14:18]  webpack finished in 8.11 s
    [01:14:18]  sass started ...
    Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find                                                                                                                 Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this w                                                                                                                arning.
    [01:14:20]  sass finished in 1.81 s
    [01:14:20]  postprocess started ...
    [01:14:20]  postprocess finished in 31 ms
    [01:14:20]  lint started ...
    [01:14:20]  build dev finished in 15.49 s
    > cordova run android --target 95142bf1
    Android Studio project detected


    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Win 7\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
    studio
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Subproject Path: app
    publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now                                                                                                                 published.

    Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' in                                                                                                                stead.
    The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be re                                                                                                                moved in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

            at build_85bbhcbf5ogx3eqe0v2ws0it5.run(C:\Users\Win 7\Desktop\ThePfe\pfe                                                                                                                z\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:146)
    :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
     UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
     UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
     UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
     UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

    UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes

    NO-SOURCE
    :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
     UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild

    :app:compileDebugAidl
     UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
     UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources

    Error: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Win 7\Desktop\ThePfe\pfez\platforms\andro                                                                                                                id\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-pa-                                                                                                                rIN'.
    :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
(node:5844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\Win 7\Desktop\ThePfe\pfez\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Win 7\Desktop\ThePfe\pfez\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:5844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5844) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I even tried to make a brand new blank project, i installed the plugin and added what needs to be added to app.module.ts and it didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make a new projet installing only this plugin and it didnt work, so i guess problem has something to do with the plugin itself

Answer (score 0):

Error: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\ThePfe\pfez\platforms\andro...
Seems like it could be a permissions problem that your user may not have for the particular directory/file being deleted

EDIT:

Looks like you have a plugin conflict somewhere

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Indicates that you have multiple references in your plugins to the support library, but the versions they require don't match.

Comment: The app is working juste fine, when i install the plugin and add it to imports and providers it doesnt work anymore

Comment: Right, it seems to me, and I'm not any expert here as I've never used that plugin, that whatever the plugin is adding is not deleteable when it tries to build your project. What is the file it is trying to delete?

Comment: I changed the path of the projet and somehow the Could not delete error disappeared, im getting another error, i edited the post check the error im getting now

Comment: U mean that i have multiple versions of Local Notification Installed?

Comment: I made some research, i think it has something to do with Gradle but i dont really know how to solve this

Comment: I even tried to make a brand new blank project, i installed the plugin and added what needs to be added to app.module.ts and it didnt work either

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. It sounds like a problem with the environment you are building the project in. Unless there are reported issues for this on the plugins repository